# Spring Security: How to use MethodInvocation instead of FilterInvocation

Tags: spring-security

For some reason the authoritieObject I was expecting at my vote() method is an instance of FilterInvocation, and I needed a MethodInvocation. Can't figure out why this is happening.

My web.xml is the following:

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

my applicationContext:

```
<b:bean id="_methodDefinitionSourceAdvisor" class="org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodDefinitionSourceAdvisor">
    <b:constructor-arg value="_methodSecurityInterceptor" />
    <b:constructor-arg ref="_delegatingMethodDefinitionSource" />
</b:bean>
```

where MethodSecurityInterceptor is defined like this:

```
    <b:bean id="_methodSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor">
...

    </b:bean>
```

and delegatingMethodDefinitionSource, like this:

```
    <b:bean id="_delegatingMethodDefinitionSource" class="org.springframework.security.intercept.method.DelegatingMethodDefinitionSource">
...

    </bean>
```

Any clue? I could really use a little help!

Comment: Actually, I just discovered what happened. Someone took off the aspectj:autoproxy tag out of one of our xml configuration files. Because of that, spring was not correctly instantiating our beans, leaving the interceptor to the default one: FilterInterceptor. Thanks for trying to help, anyway... I'll be posting the answer here asap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to put a missing `<aspectj:autoproxy/>` tag on the configuration xmls. This makes the beans autoproxied by the security interceptor.